# Provisioning a default.aspx page to use a custom page layout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom site definition I created that deploys a couple of custom page layouts.  Does anyone know what needs to be done so that when a user uses my site definition to create a site, their default.aspx page is created using my custom page layout?

Below is the module section of my site definition:

```
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="DefaultHome" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
        <Property Name="Title" Value="Test Home Page" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustomPageLayout.aspx, My Custom PageLayout" />
        <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
        <Property Name="PublishingPageContent" Value="Welcome to the My Test Publishing Site" />
      </File>
    </Module>
  </Modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onet.xml file you need to set the DefaultPageLayout property like below

```
<!-- Publishing Feature -->
        <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/Default.aspx" />
            <Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyMasterPage.master"/>
            <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="True" />
            <Property Key="VersioningOnPages" Value="Major" />
            <Property Key="RequireCheckoutOnPages" Value="False" />
            <Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyPageLayout.aspx:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyPageLayout.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyPageLayout.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value="ENTERWIKIRBKC#2;"/>                       
            <Property Key="AllowSpacesInNewPageName" Value="false"/>
          </Properties>
        </Feature>
```

Comment: I was able to get it working.  I had to update my default.aspx page such that it doesn't include any content placeholders.

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> 
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/default.master" %>

This page originally inherited from WebPartPage, therefore the page layout couldn't be applied.  Thanks!

Comment: @mawaru: you should add an answer with your success. You can then accept it as the answer and get upvotes for it.

Answer (score 0):

The default.aspx page in SiteDefinition created by VS inherits from webpart page. Make sure that you delete all the code and add the below. This has worked for me.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> 
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>
```